# Parameter substitution in sh -c

Tags: linux, bash

I have a large number of log files, the idea is to group them by date/month and then pack into archives. 
Here's my script:

```
find /c/this/path/ -type f -name "$file_pattern" | xargs -I fn basename fn | cut -c$start-$end | uniq | xargs -I {} sh -c "tar zcvf {}-$postfix.tgz {}$file_pattern"
```

all variables are defined. However, when I execute this (call a function which contains this script), the archive is not created and no errors are shown. When I run this manually, with hardcoded parameters, it works fine. My guess is I screwed up with parameter substitution.
By the way, I run this on Windows using commands that come with msysgit installation (if this makes any difference).

Comment: Insert an `echo ` before `sh -c` to see what happens.

Comment: Have you export them? Because sh -c invoke new subshell

Comment: @RomeoNinov what do you mean by export?

Comment: export VARIABLE=value

Comment: @RomeoNinov I see. no, variables are defined inside a script and read from parameters

Comment: OK, but if you do not export them they will be not available in subshell!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you want to know how to pass arguments to the script specified by `-c`

```
...|xargs -I {} sh -c 'tar zcvf "$1"-'"$postfix"'.tgz "$1"'"$file_pattern" _ {}
```

The first argument after the script (`_`) will become `$0` in `sh`, and the next argument (`{}` from xargs) will be `$1`.  The mix of single and double quotes is a bit messy but needed since you have some params you need to substitute *now* and some you need the `sh` to handle.

Comment: +1. More in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/108618).

Answer (score 0):

You have to call your variables like this `${variable}` instead of `$variable` it is also convention to write it in Caps like so `${VARIABLE}`

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that I understand the problem. Script itself is fine. file_pattern is defined like: `file_pattern=*.log` However, in current directory I had file that matches that wildcard (e.g. something.log) - and file_pattern variable was filled with that file's name. After I wrapped file_pattern evaluation in double quotes, everything was fine. May be someone will tell me why such an expansion? 
**EDIT** I escaped the asterisk like this: `file_pattern=\*.log` and script works fine now